# AWS Lambda function for Trim Video

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I want to create a Lambda function that invoked whenever someone uploads to the S3 bucket. The purpose of the function is to take the uploaded file and Trim video from start to 30seconds and save it to s3.

Comment: What approach have you used to achieve this purpose ?

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer used aws mediaConverter dotnet sdk but want aws lambda

Comment: What problem are you facing with this approach?

Comment: Are you able to trim the video using lambda function, right ?